# display key and value from object and convert into html links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take the key and values from an array and convert it to a list of links.

This is my variable

```
var MyObj = [{
    "1": "Val_1",
    "2": "Val_2",
    "3": "Val_3",
}];
```

This is how I'm trying to get the links to look like

```
<a href="/?categories='+ MyObj[0].key +'&type='+MyObj[0].value+'/">MyObj[0].value</a>
```

I've been trying various methods but to no concrete result, the closest I came was and output in the console.log that state [Object object]

Comment: could you please check your var MyObj syntax please? **It is not clear if it is a hash or an array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the keys of an Object, you should use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method.

Then you can loop over your object's keys and build your links. In order to return an array of links, it's better to use the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method :

```js
var MyObj = {
    "1": "Val_1",
    "2": "Val_2",
    "3": "Val_3",
};

var links = Object.keys(MyObj).map(function(key) {
  return '<a href="/?categories='+ key + '&type=' + MyObj[key] + '/">' + MyObj[key] + '</a>';
});

console.log(links);
```

You can run the snippet and see the result.

**OR**, in ES6 syntax :

```
const links = Object.keys(MyObj).map(key => `<a href="/?categories=${key}&type=${MyObj[key]}/">${MyObj[key]}</a>`);
```

Comment: interesting, this is the [output](http://imgur.com/IF6wMcy) from my console, same goes for the es6 sytax but the objects are undefined

Comment: Oops, it was my fault, I typed the ES6 part without verifying, it was wrong, I updated the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correct. You can achieve what you want as shown below:

```
//declare variable
var MyObj ={
    "1": "Val_1",
    "2": "Val_2",
    "3": "Val_3",
};   

//declare an array where you are going to store your elements
var newArray = [];
for(key in MyObj){ //loop over keys of MyObj object variable 
//string variable where we concatenate key and value as below
  var str = "/?categories="+ key +"&type="+MyObj[key]+"/";
  newArray.push(str);//we push this string value to the newArray declared outside of the loop
}

console.log(newArray);//to see the result on the console
//let me know if you have more questions in the comments
```

Comment: at least throw some explanation :O

Comment: I get the same output as the other solution here is the [link](http://imgur.com/IF6wMcy)

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you. Try modifying string variable (**str**) to your need.

Answer (score 0):

That's an Object, not an array.

An array uses this syntax:

```
var myArr = ["Val_1", "Val_2"]
```

And you can easily loop through an array using a for loop

```js
var myArray = ["val_1", "val_2"]

for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    let url = "<a href=\"/?categories=" + i +"&type="+myArray[i]+"\">" +myArray[i]+"</a>"
    console.log(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you should use [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/).
It will transform your object into url string